# Changing app 'sent from' email address in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I was just creating the 'reset password' section for my app using Firebase (built for iOS with Swift) and wondered if I was able to change the email address that the reset password link is sent from?

For example, instead of it being 'noreply@appid.firebase.com', could I change it to 'noreply@myappswebsiteurl.com'?

I can't seem to find anything on how this can be done and I guess it's not really hugely important but it's just something I might want to change in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Firebase console you can find Templates tab in Authentication. There you can change sender name  [image: template settings]

refer at **Customize the sender domain** in
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714

You should add domain in Firebase console.
[image: customize sender domain]

You can also use SMTP for emails 
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe it was so easy!

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to the firebase console ==> Authentication Part:

[image: Authentication console]

Click on the pencil to edit, then click customize domain:

[image]

works with password reset, email address verification, email address change.